# Messaging extension on query result select item is not invoked on Android/IOS Teams app

Tags: android, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have made an app for Teams that I want to use to display an adaptive card to the user when they pick an item from the list of search results. In order for this to happen, I need to trigger some code after the user selects a result. This works as expected from the Teams client, as well as in the browser, but from native mobile Teams app, the code is not triggered when selecting an item from the list of results.

```
const preview = CardFactory.heroCard( obj.package.name );
preview.content.tap = { type: 'invoke', value: { description: obj.package.description } };
```

The following pictures show the app working in a browser on the computer:

[The list of results from the browser on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmlAk.png)

[The expected adaptive card showing correctly on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKwmA.png)

And this is how it looks from the mobile perspective:

[The list of results from mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA28n.jpg)

[The result of selecting the same item from the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arqa7.jpg)

The code used to display this has not been modified, except providing a bot to host it, and was found from Microsoft's bot samples on GitHub:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/typescript_nodejs/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search

The code in question looks as follows:

```
export class TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
  public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery( context: TurnContext, query: any ): Promise<any> {
    const searchQuery = query.parameters[ 0 ].value;
    const response = await axios.get( `http://registry.npmjs.com/-/v1/search?${ querystring.stringify( { text: searchQuery, size: 8 } ) }` );

    const attachments = [];
    response.data.objects.forEach( ( obj: any ) => {
      const heroCard = CardFactory.heroCard( obj.package.name );
      const preview = CardFactory.heroCard( obj.package.name );
      preview.content.tap = { type: 'invoke', value: { description: obj.package.description } };
      const attachment = { ...heroCard, preview };
      attachments.push( attachment );
    } );

    return {
      composeExtension: {
        attachmentLayout: 'list',
        attachments,
        type: 'result'
      }
    };
  }

  public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItem( context: TurnContext, obj: any ): Promise<any> {
    return {
      composeExtension: {
        attachmentLayout: 'list',
        attachments: [ CardFactory.thumbnailCard( obj.description ) ],
        type: 'result'
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Is this expected?

Thanks

Edit: Adding the manifest JSON used here:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "9211fa66-f930-414d-861a-40f18f7f1490",
  "packageName": "com.teams.sample.teamsmessagingextensionssearch",
  "developer": {
    "name": "teamsStartNewThreadInChannel",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.teams.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.teams.com/termsofuser"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Search Messaging Extension",
    "full": "Microsoft Teams Search Based Messaging Extension"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Sample demonstrating a Search Based Messaging Extension",
    "full": "Sample Search Messaging Extension built with the Bot Builder SDK"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "9211fa66-f930-414d-861a-40f18f7f1490",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "groupchat",
        "team"
      ],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "9211fa66-f930-414d-861a-40f18f7f1490",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "searchQuery",
          "context": [
            "compose",
            "commandBox"
          ],
          "description": "Test command to run query",
          "title": "Search",
          "type": "query",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "searchQuery",
              "title": "Search Query",
              "description": "Your search query",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": []
}
```

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end could you please share teams version?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT The Teams version is 1416/1.0.0.2021063702, and it is on a OnePlus 5T (A5010) running OxygenOS 10.0.1

Comment: We are trying to repro at our end, will update you soon

Comment: Could you please share your manifest?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I have edited the post to add the manifest. Note that the GUID for the bot has been replaced with a random GUID

Answer (score 0):

We are able to re-pro the issue at our end. Raised a bug.We are tracking the bug internally, we don't have ETA to share when it will be fixed. Will update once it is fixed.