# Microsoft Teams: Messaging extension on query result select item is not invoked on iOS

Tags: ios, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm building a Microsoft Teams bot with Compose Extension (Search extension) functionality. As soon as the user opens the search extension it fetches results from the backend. I'm using thumbnail cards to show the result list. I have also added **tap** functionality into thumbnail cards. That means when a user selects a result a backend **invoke** call will be triggered with some specific data and with that data I build an adaptive card.

This feature works well in Teams mac, web, and android apps. But with the native iOS app, the invoke call is never triggered when a user selects a result. Instead, it sends a thumbnail card on the Teams compose area.

This is the response I'm building for the Search extension

```
{
    "composeExtension": {
        "type": "result",
        "attachmentLayout": "list",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",
                "content": {
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://localhost:8080/Public/img3-a68ff7.jpeg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "subtitle": "Thumbnail card subtitle",
                    "tap": {
                        "type": "invoke",
                        "value": {
                            "type": "IDEA_SELECT_CALLBACK",
                            "selectedItemId": 7082
                        }
                    },
                    "text": "Thumbnail card text",
                    "title": "Title"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image from ios where a thumbnail card is thrown in compose area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEBcV.png)

[ideal result from PC/mac where **invoke** command triggered and the adaptive card is built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzkHI.png)

Mac/PC screenshots

[image: search list]

[image: on select search item]

Android screenshots

[image: search list]

[image: on select search item]

iOS screenshots

[image: search list]

[image: on select search item]

Code example from ms github

[image: code example from ms github]

Comment: We are checking this issue ,It's working fine from our end.SelectItemAsync 
is triggered in android as well as IOS teams application.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXtCS.png
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K28pC.png
Ref sample-https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT what version of teams you are using in iOS?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT my issue is similar to the following issue. Can you please confirm if the bug that is mentioned is fixed or not?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67801528/messaging-extension-on-query-result-select-item-is-not-invoked-on-android-ios-te?rq=1

Comment: Yes.This issue is fixed.
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHWD7.png

Comment: Could you please update the teams version and check it once?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I using the exact same version as yours

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT updated the Teams version to 4.11.0. The issue remains unfixed.

Comment: means issue occur in compose area.Thumbnail card not showing properly or after sending it is not showing properly?

Comment: I don't want to show the thumbnail card in compose area. It doesn't show on other environments except for iOS. I want the exact same behavior in iOS also. In iOS `tap` on the selected item doesn't invoke.

Comment: as you mention ,We are checking from our end.Could u please confirm you get like below screenshot?
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwOly.jpg
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/roBCI.png

Comment: Yes, I do get like your screenshots. Which is not ideal behaviour. In other devices on a select search item `invoke` gets called. But in iOS thumbnail card is shown.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I am adding the screenshots in the description for all three environments (mac, ios, android). You'll see that they are not behaving the same. For iOS, the preview item is showing in compose box instead of invoking `tap` action. Please see the screenshots with headings `Mac/PC screenshots`, `Android screenshots`, `iOS screenshots`

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Please try to reproduce this issue. If possible create a bug ticket.

Comment: Could you please try with below sample?
Sample link-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search

Comment: I tried the above sample and preview shown in IOS, Web , android and desktop.
video-https://youtu.be/aom6FLFZIZ4

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I've seen the example. According to the GitHub example, the Preview is optional, if it includes a Tap, that will trigger the OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync event back on this bot. But in iOS, OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync is not triggered. Instead, it throws the thumbnail card on the compose area. Please check if it triggers OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync on iOS device or not. Please check the screenshot.
[![code example from ms github example][9]][9]
[9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiirn.png

Comment: We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT thank you. Looking forward to the fix.

Comment: Issue is resolved.Could you please check it once with the updated version.
Teams Version-5.7.77.2023073202/0421(general)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have made some changes to the response object. I've added the `review` property and instead of setting `tap` to the `content`, I'm setting it to the `review`. Doing so, invoke is triggered on selecting a search result but it also pastes the Hero Card on the compose area on my iOS device.

Here is the exact same response I'm building...

```
{
    "composeExtension": {
        "type": "result",
        "attachmentLayout": "list",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",
                "content": {
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "url": "https:/localhost/93/937083/Public/img3-a68ff7.jpeg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "subtitle": "Subtitle",
                    "text": "Sample text",
                    "title": "Thumbnail card title"
                },
                "preview": {
                    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                    "content": {
                        "buttons": null,
                        "images": [
                            {
                                "url": "https:/localhost/93/937083/Public/img3-a68ff7.jpeg"
                            }
                        ],
                        "subtitle": "Subtitle",
                        "tap": {
                            "type": "invoke",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "SELECT_CALLBACK",
                                "selectedItemId": 1001
                            }
                        },
                        "text": "Sample text",
                        "title": "Thumbnail card title"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[hero card on the compose area and adaptive card on the background built by invoked value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1kAE.jpg)